# How to write a phone number for calling in android but not make the call

Tags: java, android, phone-number, phone-call

I want to have an action onClick on a button in some activity that just writes a phone number in the agenda screen, but not call it. I have to let the user decide if he wants to call or not.

What I have found by now is this code, that works perfectly, but it's not really what I need. With this code, when I click the button, it calls the selected

```
private OnClickListener callToAction = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick sticky from homepage.");
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*123"));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Intent.ACTION_DIAL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL) to open the dialer instead of connecting the call.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use other Intent Action for that.
Try `Intent.ACTION_DIAL`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL
or `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW

Example from Intent documentation:

> ACTION_VIEW tel:123 -- Display the phone dialer with the given number filled in. Note how the VIEW action does what what is considered the most reasonable thing for a particular URI.
>   ACTION_DIAL tel:123 -- Display the phone dialer with the given number filled in.